# ui-router resolve use angular-loading-bar?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

What I want to do is to use the ui-router resolution angular install-bar.

How can I run the codes given in Resolve?

```
resolve: {
return {
    loadedData: function($rootScope, $q) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $rootScope.$on('cfpLoadingBar:completed', function() {
            console.log("complete");
            deferred.resolve();
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
};
```

}

In terms of being an example;

```
greeting: function($q, $timeout){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
        $timeout(function() {
            deferred.resolve('Hello!');
        }, 1000);
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Instead of

I want to run this code, it works every timeout.
Rootscope.on works only when the page is loaded.

```
greeting: function($q, $rootScope){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
        $rootScope.$on('cfpLoadingBar:completed', function(){
            deferred.resolve('Hello!');
        });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: You can do it by adding it in the resolve object under your state:

`resolve:{
         // Example using function with simple return value.
         // Since it's not a promise, it resolves immediately.
         simpleObj:  function(){
            return {value: 'simple!'};
         },`

Comment: @Cemal Can you please clearly mention what is your problem ? What do you want to run in the resolve block of a route ?

Comment: Yeah, I'm working it that way.
I forgot to add all the code here.

The event I want to do is shudder;

$ RootScope. $ On ('$ stateChangeStart', function (event, toState) {})

I do not want the page to change when this code is running.
I want the page to change when all requests from the opposite side of the page are completed.
Is it possible?

Comment: @Cemal, I don't think the resolve object is the place to do that, because logic in resolve object is only executed before transation to that state and then it would be resolved. try to understand  [resolve ](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve)

Comment: I am running this way, $timeout(function() { deferred.resolve ();}); only here Instead of $rootScope.$on('cfpLoadingBar:completed', function () {deferred.resolve ();

I want to use it, I am using only the page change does not work.